# Problems with ResultSet

Tags: java, sql

Look at the code below. The issue here is that the query returns one column(LOGIN) with no rows(that is what SQL Developer says), rs.next() is being proceed and rs.getString(1) returns the first row from table Users. I do not understand the fact that under the field currentRow in ResultSet is value of -1. It would mean that it gets one row from the query which is a mass incoherence. How should I force next() method not to step forward if there's no row returned?

```
ResultSet rs = null;
String name = null;
Statement stat = db.conn.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT Users.LOGIN FROM Users, Accessibility WHERE Accessibility.Users_IDGRANTING=4 AND Users.ID=Accessibility.Users_IDRECEIVING";
rs = stat.executeQuery(query);

while(rs.next()) 
{
name = rs.getString(1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents of `rs.getString(1)`? Probably you're connecting to another database in your tests.

Comment: Name contains what is in getString(1). It's the first record, first column in the the table Users. I do not posess another database.

Comment: I am afraid of asking if the ResultSet was returned by some Statement :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've just edited the code.

Comment: Are you running the posted code (exactly as it's shown)?

Comment: Is this your exact, real, cut and pasted code? Or is this just a summary that you've typed in here? Perhaps the real code has a problem not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor of [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is initially positioned **before** the first record. So if `rs` is empty, then `rs.next()` will return `false` right away and your while loop will immediately exit.  Just check whether your rs was created by another statements.

Answer (score 0):

"How should I force next() method not to step forward if there's no row returned?"
That's what it does, rs.next() will be false in such case.

Comment: As I said, SQL Developer reacts on the mentioned query(I literally copy the query from debugging mode) - no rows, one column available.

The code I posted reacys in such way. rs { currentRow=-1 fetchedRowCount=1, maxRows=0 } and rs.next() does not return false. It returns a row. I don't have any idea why.

Comment: Try using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to see if that fixes the problem. The code you show here should work fine.